# what is the natural map from BP to $HF_p$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, spectral-sequences

what is the natural map from BP to $HF_p$?
BP is the Brown-Peterson spectrum and $HF_p$ is Eilenberg Maclane spectrum.

I am trying to learn the connections between ASS and ANSS. This map should induce a map of spectral sequence.

Thanks.

Comment: I am no expert, but such a map is certainly given by a cohomology class in $BP$. Since $BP$ is connective, maybe you can produce a natural example by considering the Hurewicz map to produce an integral homology class and then use universal coefficient?